# Where to find new ERC20 tokens?

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, tokens

Hope you are all doing good. Could someone help me to find out where to get information about new ERC20 tokens? Like DEX listing announcement or smth like that, when a token is available for buying for the first time?

Comment: This can be a helpful site, but in this case there are different kinds of IDO e.g.: for NFT launchpad, ERC20 Token, and others. Link: https://listingspy.net/ido/upcoming

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ways to do it, using online service or checking the blockchain yourself:

1. Check the blockchain: DEX listing is simply people creating trading pair on popular dex (Uniswap, SushiSwap, Pancakeswap, etc). To check all of this you have to check their factory to create trading pair. For example :

- [Uniswap V2 Factory](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f)
- [Pancake Swap Factory](https://bscscan.com/address/0xca143ce32fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fc5350c73)
- [Uniswap (V3) has changed to Position NFT](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88)

In uniswap, pancakeswap and most Dex you can clearly see the "Dex listing" is when the transaction `createPair` was confirmed. This one alone doesn't check for liquidity and the price or authenticity of the token. It's very likely (>99%) of the time that you will be rugged if you check directly on blockchain.

2. Using services: for a bit more trust when devs lock their LP tokens: Usually devs will try to lock their liquidity using a third party service to increase trust (which means they cant dump the LP tokens until timeout). One of the popular liquidity locking services I know is Unicrypt, you can check [all locking, upcoming presale and live sale](https://app.unicrypt.network/dashboard). Although the LP tokens are locked here, it's not completely safe: malicious devs may still have other ways to manipulate the price and rug pull users using the backdoors in their token's smartcontract (e.g. they can lock all users trading and only allow their wallets to trade or mint token arbitrarily to their wallet).

These methods are still very high risk but you have a chance to check and verify all information on your own instead of reading from website or telegram. This answer is just providing information, not financial advice to buy anything from these services.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the dex contract address for when a pair is created using [Moralis streams API](https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api), you will receive webhooks which you can use to create a notification system.

Here you can find an example: https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api/how-to-listen-all-events-from-a-contract-factory

Let me know if you need any help!

Disclosure: I work at Moralis